# arrow keys to select text like in swype

Tags: android

I am learning android programming and have taken the task of creating my own IME.
I am using LatinIME as a base for this and creating my own SWYPE keyboard.

How can I implement the select-text with arrow keys that we have in SWYPE?
I have implemented the arrow-keys and can move the cursor around, but do not know how to make the selection work. It might just be that I have to set some flag that I do not know of.

The InputConnection.setSelection(start, end) is one available function, but do not getting how to correctly set those values either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. just had to send:

```
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT);
```

---

8 hrs = 1 line. need to sleep now

Comment: That doesn't have any effect for me, the cursor doesn't move. Did you do something extra ?